# Python, issues with extracting all expressions from a line (only the first one extracted)

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and I'm currently working on a python script to extract temporal expressions from a text and transform them in real dates.

I sometimes have several temporal expressions in one line, however my code only retrieves the first expression. Each expression starts with '{' and ends with '}'.

I have already tried a few things (while loops, for loops), but I can't find how I should make it work. I also tried to split the line in two, but the script bugs...

Here's my function:

```
    for in_line in file: 
       with open('file.txt', 'a+') as outfile:
           if '{' in in_line: 
               start_expression = in_line.find('{')
               start_values = in_line.find("values=")
               end = in_line.find("}")
               expression_temporelle = in_line[start_expression:end+1]
               values = in_line[start_values+7:end]
               print expression_temporelle
               self.retrieve_expression(expression_temporelle, values, in_line, outfile)
```

(NB : the rest of the code functions, and if the expressions are in different lines, all are taken and transformed correctly)

And here is what it prints: (I run the original text on another program, which renders it to this format)

```
    {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015} // temporal expression extracted
    Reçu le [20-4-2015], CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961}) // new sentence with only the first expression transformed
```

Thank you for your help :)

Sorry, I realise I was not very clear on what I send to the script etc. 
I give a text to the script, right now (and for the answers shown above), I give "Reçu le {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015}
CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961})" to the script (the original text said "Reçu le 20 avril 2015, CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (né le 07/04/1961)" but was modified through another program).

So the problem is I only extract the first temporal expression in the line...

Comment: Try splitting the line on `}` which will give you a list. Then process each item in the list.

Comment: When I do that, I have as results: Reçu le [20-4-2015], CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961})
... The first line is still the only one handled :/

Comment: Without a decent sample of the data, it's difficult to know what is happening. I see only one date in {} brackets in the sample you provided

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I edited my question, hope it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following data in file abc.txt:

```
Reçu le {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015} CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961})
Reçu le {21 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=21+avril+2015} CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Reçu le {22 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=22+avril+2015} CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Reçu le {23 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=23+avril+2015} CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961})
```

A simple `str.split('}')` on each line in the file will do the job

```
infile = open('abc.txt','r')
line_count = 0
for in_line in infile:
    line_count +=1
    parts = in_line.split('}')
    part_count = 0
    for part in parts:
        if '{' in part:
            part_count +=1
            start_expression = part.find('{')
            start_values = part.find("values=")
            expression_temporelle = part[start_expression:]
            values = part[start_values+7:]
            print "line", str(line_count)
            print "    part", str(part_count)
            print "        ", expression_temporelle+"}" #add back the } for printing
infile.close()
```

Result:

```
line 1
    part 1
         {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015}
line 1
    part 2
         {07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961}
line 2
    part 1
         {21 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=21+avril+2015}
line 3
    part 1
         {22 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=22+avril+2015}
line 4
    part 1
         {23 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=23+avril+2015}
line 4
    part 2
         {07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961}
```

You could use `re` rather than a standard split i.e. `parts = re.split('(})', in_line)` which would leave the `}` in the list.

```
>>> x = "Reçu le {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015} CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961})"
>>> s = x.split('}')
>>> s
['Re\xc3\xa7u le {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015', ' CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961', ')']
>>> s = re.split('(})', x)
>>> s
['Re\xc3\xa7u le {20 avril 2015,20 avril 2015.Time+Date+format=JJ_mois_AAAA+values=20+avril+2015', '}', ' CONCERNE : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({07/04/1961,07/04/1961.Time+Date_naissance+format=JJ-MM-AAAA+values=07-04-1961', '}', ')']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an re.findall() inside your loop to turn your temporal expressions into lists. Feed each line of the file into this to split it up and then maybe append them to a new list.

```
re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', line)
```